# Dialogo con campo contraseña en GWT

Tags: java, gwt

tengo el siguiente código:

```
    @Override
                    public void onClick(
                            com.smartgwt.client.widgets.events.ClickEvent event) {


                        Dialog dialog = new Dialog();


                        dialog.setWidth(200);



                        SC.askforValue("Confirmación", "Introduzca la Password:", "", new ValueCallback() {
                           @Override
                           public void execute(String value) {
                                if (!value.isEmpty()) {
                                    //SC.say(value);
                                    if (value == ("Contraseña")){
                                        ...
}
```

Lo que me ejecuta un dialogo donde me pregunta la contraseña, pero mi duda es como puedo hacer que ese campo contraseña sea del tipo contraseña, es decir, para que el usuario no vea lo que esta escribiendo si no los típicos caracteres de puntos.

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

> pero mi duda es como puedo hacer que ese campo contraseña sea del tipo
>   contraseña,

En realidad no existe el tipo "contraseña", lo que se debe recibir para que la comparación sea correcta es que obtengas en el callback para la variable `value` el valor "Contraseña".

---

Este es un ejemplo de como debería funcionar.

```
String value = "Contraseña";

  if (value == ("Contraseña")){             
      System.out.println("Contraseña!!!");
  }else{
      System.out.println("NO es igual a Contraseña!!!");
  }
```